# Facebook Instant Gaming Matchmaking blocked on "The player is not currently eligible to match."

Tags: facebook, fig, matchmaking, facebook-instant-games

I have setup the matchmaking code and actually got it working 3 times where it searched, waited, and then found a match (my other account also set to search), without any problems.

Then all of a sudden both of them stopped working with the only message being: `The player is not currently eligible to match.`

This is the code (pretty generic):

```
FBInstant.checkCanPlayerMatchAsync().then(function(canMatch) {
    console.log("Player can match: ", canMatch);
    if (canMatch) {
     // ok if we can, let's search //
     console.log("searching for match...", tag);
     FBInstant.matchPlayerAsync(tag, true).then(function() {
         console.log(FBInstant.context.getID());
     }).catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
     });
   }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

`tag` is `match_bounty`

Does anyone have any idea why this stopped working?

Edit: If I create a new account, with the same code it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with `v6.2` of the Instant Games SDK.

`v6.1` works as expected for 3 matches and then its locked again.

Comment: The 3 match limit is intentional to prevent too much low value thread creation, although we are soon rolling out a change that will remove this limitation for developers to make things easier to test.

Was the official answer I got on the Facebook Instant Games developers group.